# How to save the first element of a row from a list to a new variable?

Tags: r

I got a list variable 'bracket', which dimensions are n x m, where n denotes the rows, and m denotes the number of elements in the given row. However, n is constant, but m varies.

```
> bracket
[[1]]
[1] 8

[[2]]
[1] 11 22

[[3]]
[1] 13 25

[[4]]
[1] 18
```

I would like to see the following:

```
> bracket
[1]  8 11 13 18
```

How can I do that? Thank you for your help!

---

After using `sapply(bracket, '[[', 1)`, I had some trouble. I got the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds. What to do if I have got some rows with no value/NA?

Comment: I got the following error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds.
What to do if I have got some rows with no value/NA?

Comment: @zx8754 It is not a dupe.  The OP had some other problems.

Comment: NAs don't matter. Empty slots though will result to the error. To overcome them you can just simply do `sapply(bracket[lengths(bracket) != 0], '[[', 1)`

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar `sapply()` is diving into the list working on each element. Try `sapply(bracket, '[', 1)`

Comment: Be wary though as that will give `NA` for any empty slots and considering you already have NAs then this might confuse things a bit

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar Can you make your example reproducible? Your current example doesn't exhibit that issue and when I have an empty element or an element that is just NA I don't get the error that you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I produced a data example on my own to reproduce the error:

```
bracket <- list(8, c(11, 22), c(13, 25), 18)
sapply(bracket, '[[', 1) # will not reproduce the error
sapply(bracket, '[', 1)  # will not reproduce the error

bracket <- list(8, c(11, 22), numeric(0), c(13, 25), 18)
sapply(bracket, '[[', 1)  # will reproduce the error
sapply(bracket, '[', 1)   # gives NA

na.omit(sapply(bracket, '[', 1)) # omits the NAs
```